# Can't handle a SearchView on android

Tags: java, android, searchview, android-toolbar

I was trying to add and handle a SearchView in the toolbar according to the second asnwer of this topic
 [How to add search button on toolbar in material design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893534/how-to-add-search-button-on-toolbar-in-material-design/29893683#29893683?newreg=ac51ca367cd141068b6e209fa7e202f6)

However, I have such a mistake:

Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute 'ActionViewClass' in package 'com.example.user.mobinfouz'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here's my code of the menu_main xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:ActionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set attribute like this :

```
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

instead of

```
app:ActionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```